# Glimpse Broken Again

Tags: glimpse

Back from my post here
[Glimpse making everything 50x slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253737/glimpse-making-everything-50x-slower)

It was fixed but now is broken again.

It seems to again try to hash every bit of data in the relationships of tables even though the code doesnt do this, glimpse forces this.

Because of this glimpse isn't responding and we get the error

No data has been found. This could be caused because:

```
- the data is still loading by the client, or
- no data has been received from the server (check to see if the data & metadata payloads are present), or
- no plugin has been loaded, or
- an error has been thrown in the client (please check your JavaScript console and let us know if anything is up).
```

this is what it looks like in chrome
http://puu.sh/cF3xX/0f879fac9c.png

this is what ends up happening debugging locally
http://puu.sh/cF2c6/e10ca1b6e0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, make sure you are not using any data model in the Views. This can cause the issue that you described due to lazy loading attempting to map all the connections (relationships).

Comment: You are correct. Removing any use of a data model fixed the issue. However this is still a Glimpse bug. Using glimpse shouldn't make a website that works crash.